# Kotlin: Spread operator on calling JavaScript method

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js-interop, kotlin-js

I try to write a type-safe wrapper for a JavaScript library.
I need to call a method from JavaScript with variable arguments
(e.g. `method(args...)`).
The Kotlin fun for this should work with variable arguments, too.
Because Kotlin supports a spread operator, I tried to use it, but Kotlin do not want this.

Example code:

```
val jsLibrary: dynamic = require("library") // library given by node's require here
fun method(vararg args: String) = jsLibrary.method(*args)
```

Edit: Forgot to write spread operator '*' in code already. Compiler returns error because of the spread operator.

The Kotlin compiler returns the error "Can't apply spread operator in dynamic call".

Any ideas how to implement a wrapper like this, or do I need any workaround?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try it without spread operator `jsLibrary.method(args)` ?

Comment: What is the signature of `jsLibrary.method()` method?

Comment: Your wrapper method is not entirely type-safe, return type will be inferred as `dynamic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`external fun`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-interop.html#external-modifier) with [`@JsModule`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-modules.html#jsmodule-annotation) annotation

```
@JsModule("library")
external fun method(vararg args: String): LibraryMethodReturnType
```

This will do `require("library")` for you under the hood. You'll have proper Kotlin types instead of `dynamic` right away. You'll have no "wrappers", meaning no extra JavaScript call at runtime.

---

There is a hacky solution if for you want to manually use `require` and `dynamic` types: use `apply` method to pass all the arguments as an array.

```
val jsLibrary: dynamic = require("library")
fun method(vararg args: String) = jsLibrary.method.apply(null, args)
```